# Why are my UTF-8 filenames in bugzilla downloading as quoted-printable filenames?

Tags: bugzilla

I have a bugzilla install set up with English and Japanese templates to support our users in the US and Japan.  My users are having a problem with attachments that have Japanese characters in the filename; English filenames are OK.

Say I upload a file called "Blah操作手.doc".  When I go to download the file, I get a prompt asking me to save it as "=_UTF-8_Q_Blah=E6=93=8D=E4=BD=9C=E6=89=8B_=.doc".  All of the data in the file is preserved, but the filename appears to not be decoded properly.  Often, the filename ends up so long that it loses the original extension, and the user gets a page filled with garbage if they try to open the attachment in their browser.  This is happening even though the database "filename" field displays the original characters correctly.

This is happening with all types of files that contain non-ASCII characters - doc, xls, pdf, png, txt, etc.  I was able to reproduce this on the default templates for Bugzilla 3.6.3, regardless of regional settings or template language.

This is primarily a problem for Internet Explorer.  Chrome and Safari have similar problems, but I don't really have any users that use either.  Firefox works fine and returns the original filename as expected.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very long answer to this question that somebody else may give you, but the basic problem is that there is no reasonable method of encoding UTF-8 filenames that all browsers support. I suspect that you're using IE, and it doesn't support the standard encoding method that we're using. More or less, this is something that can be worked around in Bugzilla, but we haven't done it yet. There's a bug filed for it at bugzilla.mozilla.org, but I'm not finding it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The behavior does seem to vary depending on the browser - out of IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, only Firefox had no issues with the attachment name.  Since virtually all my Japanese users use IE, do you know if there's a tweak to the encoding scheme I could make to support IE as a temporary workaround?

Comment: There might be, although I don't know it offhand. It would be some modification to attachment.cgi.

Comment: It appears that IE supports URI Escaping, so encoding the filename with uri_escape_utf8() will serve something that IE can decode and translate to the correct UTF-8 filename.  Firefox does not support this, however, so I had to cheat and use the user agent to determine when to use the URI method and when to use MIME-Q.  IE will still lose the extension even with this method unless I disable inline attachments, which is OK for my setup.  It's also worth noting that there appears to be a 100 byte limit (including the extension) on filename length which might cause other issues.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in Bugzilla 6. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619847